# How do I get all the values from a hash that are in an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have the following hash `wbs_items`:

```
wbs_items = {"Architecture"=>"architecture", "Auditing"=>"auditing", "Consulting"=>"consulting", "Delivery"=>"delivery", "Development"=>"development", "Engineering"=>"engineering", "Environment / IT"=>"environment", "Graphic Design"=>"graphic_design", "Management"=>"management", "Requirements"=>"requirements", "Research"=>"research", "Support"=>"support", "System Design"=>"system_design", "Test & Eval"=>"test_and_evaluation", "Writing"=>"writing"}
```

And the following array `disciplines`:

```
disciplines = ["architecture", "auditing", "consulting", "development", "engineering", "environment", "graphic_design", "management", "system_design", "test_and_evaluation", "writing"]
```

I want to get only the keys and values from the hash that have values from the array. How would I do that?

Comment: Your example is bad (misleading). All elements in `disciplines` exist in `wbs_items` as a value.

Comment: If you care not a whit for efficiency, you could do this: `wbs_items.to_a & wbs_items.keys.product(disciplines)` and convert to a hash if desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about :

```
wbs_items.select { |k,v| disciplines.include?(v) }
```

Comment: No. It is not perfect. Although this works, it is very inefficient.

Comment: @sawa's objection could be overcome by writing `require 'set'; dset = disciplines.to_set; wbs_items.select { |_,v| dset.include?(v) }`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
wbs_items.values & disciplines
```

Comment: This works but I want to get the key - value pair in a hash, sorry for not specifying that.

Answer (score 0):

```
inverted = wbs_items.invert
disciplines.to_enum.with_object({}){|k, h| h[inverted[k]] = k}
```

Comment: What makes this solution so much better? It didn't even work

Comment: @Snubber what do you mean it doesn't work. This solution works fine and is far more efficient than a double loop (selected answer). Might I also suggest along the same lines `disciplines.each_with_object({}) {|e,h| h[wbs_items.key(e)] = e if wbs_items.key?(e) }`

Comment: What if `h = { a:1, b:1 }; a=[1]`?  I understand the result should be `h` or `h.to_a`.